# How to provide a groupby of dates with a count from a categorical column separately

Tags: pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a transactional table that lists the gender of each person who started in one column, and the date they started in another. I want to perform a groupby that results in a data frame with a count of each gender by date. Any idea?

```
    Gender  LastStart
1   M   2013-05-21
2   M   2013-05-24
3   F   2013-05-27
4   M   2013-05-27
5   F   2013-05-28
6   F   2013-05-28
```

Should result in

```
             M   F
2013-05-21   1   0
2013-05-24   1   0
2013-05-27   1   1
2013-05-28   0   2
```

I think I need to run a groupby over a list and then a pivot but my groupby is producing a series so the pivot won't work. I'm very confused so any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html)

```
out = pd.crosstab(df['LastStart'], df['Gender'])
```

Output:

```
>>> out

Gender      F  M
LastStart       
2013-05-21  0  1
2013-05-24  0  1
2013-05-27  1  1
2013-05-28  2  0
```

If you want to remove the axis labels, i.e. `Gender` and `LastStart`, use

```
out = pd.crosstab(df['LastStart'], df['Gender']).rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use custom aggregation functions, one per column you want in the output.

```
df.groupby("LastStart").agg(
    M=("Gender", lambda s: s.eq("M").sum()),
    F=("Gender", lambda s: s.eq("F").sum()),
)
```

The “syntax” used in `.agg()` here is `<output column>=(<input column>, <aggregation function>)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it
creatng a temporary cnt value and the using pivot table

```
df.assign(cnt=1).pivot_table(index='LastStart', columns='Gender' , values='cnt', aggfunc='count').fillna(0).astype(int)
```

```
Gender      F   M
 LastStart      
2013-05-21  0   1
2013-05-24  0   1
2013-05-27  1   1
2013-05-28  2   0
```